# Why my program does not crash if destructor is called twice

Tags: c++

The code below is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "in destructor" << endl;
    }
};
void main()
{
    A a;
    a.~A();
}
```

has the following output:

```
in destructor
in destructor
```

Why my app does not crash if the destructed object is destructed again?

Comment: "undefined behaviour" means anything can happen. Crash, no crash, pink butterflies, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ Standard, section § 12.4 [destructors]

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; **the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended** ( 3.8 ). [ Example: if the destructor for an automatic object is explicitly invoked, and the block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily invoke implicit destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined.

So your program has *undefined behavior*, it could crash now, later, never, earth could stop spinning etc... don't do it.

**Note:**

- `void main()` must be `int main()`

Comment: I hope we never figure out how to make the earth stop spinning by destructing an object in C++ :)

Comment: Again oDesk test question which has only the following variant for the answers:  `a. 0
b. 1
c. 2
d. A compile time error will be generated because destructors cannot be called directly `

Comment: You should really stop reading those tests, now, and buy some good books.

Comment: Why do you have to pass that test? Is there any way to reason with the tester? Can you appeal the result on bad questions?

Comment: @quantdev Why `void main()` must be `int main()`? Both version are supported.

Comment: @Narek: Because the standard says so: It defines two signatures for `main` and declares that any other signature allowed by a conforming compiler must have a return type of `int`.

Comment: It is perfectly imaginable that the CRT will return some garbage in the place of the int it is expecting, if you declare your main() as `void`. It doesnt sound like an earth shattering problem at all, at worst, people using your process in a command line script could believe that they can rely on the 0=success convention for process exit code return value, and by chance, it could work when they test it, and some day, not work, because of different garbage present on the stack.